# Can someone explain the Bleach ending to me? [spoilers]

Tags: character-motivation, plot-device, bleach

I just read the last issue of Kubo's [Bleach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bleach_(manga)) - and I must admit I don't get it. Maybe I've missed many subtle hints, maybe I'm just dense, but - it seems like no major question was answered by the ending:

> - What exactly was the Soul King?
> - How could Yhwach be the Soul King's son? And if the Soul King can have a son, does that mean there's a "line" of Soul Kings?
> - What "broke off" the soul king's arms and 'heart' into Pernida, Gerard and Mimihagi?
> - Why did the Soul King's heart support the Soul King's destruction/assassination?
> - Why did killing Yhwach save the day? The Soul King was still destroyed, wasn't he?
> - Ostensibly, both Aizen and Yhwach had some ideas for a Soul-King-less world, and at least Aizen thought the Soul King was an abomination and was morally indignant about serving "that thing". What did they have in mind instead?
> - How was the Soul King + Seiretei + Shinigami system set up?
> - What went on before Yamamoto Shigekuni and his gang formed the 13 squadrons?

Now, I'm not asking for answers to all of these, independently. I just want to understand whether I missed something fundamental about the ending, or whether it really did just sort of leave all of these loose story threads. Or - perhaps I have missed something along the way which answers these questions by the time of the ending.

Comment: These are some good questions, but there should be one question per post. You might try editing the post to focus on one question, and ask the others separately.

Comment: @Adamant: Knowing which to separate is part of the missing information, I'd say. And it's not clear to me that the answers are separate at all.

Comment: While I suppose it's possible that (for example) the question of what the Soul King was could *inform* what Aizen and Yhwach were planning instead, they really are quite distinct questions, and it is not at all clear that the answers would be identical. And those are only two of the eight questions in this post.

Comment: @Adamant: I disagree with you. I'm looking for a general explanation of the back-story for Bleach that I find is missing, I just listed eight aspects of it.  Clarified this with an edit.

Comment: If you are looking for a general description of the backstory, that makes the question a bit *more* broad, I suppose. That's just my opinion, though. We'll see how people vote.

Comment: @Adamant: I don't want a description of the backstory, I've read all the manga and the Wiki, and I know it relatively well. The thing is, it seems there are a lot of missing pieces to the backstory which have not been filled.

Comment: I think you are right. But if there are too many plot holes to ask as separate questions, maybe you could try asking someone who has read *Bleach* in chat? Or in the Anime/Manga chat room, alternatively.

Comment: Any reason you came back to this three years later and made such a minor edit instead of fixing it to not be too broad? Seems kind of pointless to me, tbh.

Comment: @F1Krazy: The reason is I don't believe it's too broad. I didn't understand the ending, and I was trying to clarify what I was missing. But, since you asked, I'll expand the edit a bit.

Comment: This is waaaaaay too broad. There are multiple questions here which look like they have little relation to each other. Either edit this down to focus on one particular thing/question or it'll stay closed. Also asking to explain the ending seems even more broad and quite unclear. You already have multiple questions here, why not just edit it down to one of them and ask the others as separate questions?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot: 1. Disagree (especially if the answer is what I suspect it is). 2. If I were to ask each of the above as its own question, that would be kind of spammy. Also, again, I suspect the answer is "The Manga doesn't say" to each of these items.

Comment: It wouldn't be spammy it would be using the system as intended but I would recommend asking them all at once sure. And if the answer is unknown that doesn't change the fact that they are distinct questions.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot: Are you suggesting to ask them all at once, or not recommending that? :-P It looks like there's a negation missing in your comment.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Correct I meant to say would**n't**.